# AOP Aspect executes before given method even with keyword "after"?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

I`m trying to get in contact with AOP. Therefore I wrote a little helloworld, but it doesnt work as I want.

Inside the aspect I use the keyword "after", but if the given method is called, the "aspect" -  method executes before the joinpoint!?Does anyone know why?

Anything else works fine! (No exceptions!)

```
<bean id="myAspectBean" class="hello.world.MyAspect">

    </bean>

    <bean id="helloBean" class="hello.world.Hello">
        <property name="first" value="Hello"/>
        <property name="second" value="World!"/>
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="myAspectBean">
            <aop:pointcut id="pc" expression="execution(* sayHello(..))"/>
            <aop:after pointcut-ref="pc" method="doit" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just didnt debug..

The output is buffered, so the text comes before the "Hello world!", but the method is called afterwards..